# UITextField text not scrolling off on the left side

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` subclass where I have overridden some methods (see code below). The problem is that when I type in it and the text reaches the rigth margin it will no longer show what I am typing. In view debug mode I see that the `UIFieldEditor` is much wider that the text filed.

Here is the UITextFiled subclass code:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 0, 10, 15);
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 0, 10, 15);
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 0, 10, 15);
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [super editingRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, self.edgeInsets)];
}
```

Here is the code where I use this class:

```
// alloc / init 
        _myTextField.delegate = self;
        _myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _myTextField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        _myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        _myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        _myTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        _myTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        _myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        _myTextField.hidden = YES;

        _tfButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [_tfButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_edit"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self fs_addSubview:_tfButton];
        [_tfButton constrainWidth:22.];
        [_tfButton setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [_tfButton constrainHeight:22.];
        [_tfButton constrainToRightOfView:_myTextField margin:-25.0];
        [_tfButton constrainEqualCenterYWithView:_myTextField offset:0.0];
        [_tfButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


        UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)];

        _myTextField.leftView = leftView;
        _myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

How do I get the text to scroll off on the left side when the user is typing a large string in this text field?

Answer (score 11):

Your code is completely right. The problem came from the `UITextField` class.
When you dropped in a `UITextField` in your storyboard, and set it's fontSize  and minFontSize to 50. This system textField will have the same problem as your custom textField.

It's just because `UITextField` don't know how to draw big font in a narrow space.

I used your subclass of textField(with default height of 30), after I change the font size to 7, everything works fine.

Comment: I never would have though to try changing my manually set font size to fix this. You are a genius. Thank you!

Comment: This behavior is clearly described in the UITextField documentation. Haha, just kidding! Thanks for this answer, I was mystified.

Comment: Good answer. In general, this scrolling issue will happen if the height of UITextField is smaller than the height of its font size.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue, but I didn't have any UITextField subclass. 
The problem is that textfield has certain ratio between textfield height and font size. Increasing the font size above certain value w.r.t textfield height caused this issue. What I did is decreased the font size a bit and textfield started working again.

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution. It's apparently will work if you ticked "Adjust to fit" option below minimum font size (at Storyboard). Somehow the text will shrunk if typed more than right margin.

Or with code:

```
self.textField.minimumFontSize = 12;
self.textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the font size from 18 to 16 fixed it for me. Don't know why and don't care :D

```
searchTF = [UITextField new];
searchTF.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, w-140, 20);
searchTF.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchTF.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18.0f];
```

to

```
searchTF.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0f];
```

Answer (score -1):

With a bit coloring, here is what I get after trying to reproduce your code, and it looks ok to me. Could you be more specific about the expected behavior?

[image]